# InfluxDB compute total time in each state

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux-influxdb

I'm logging state changes to InfluxDB. My data looks like this:

```
2:00:00     STATE1
4:00:00     STATE2
9:00:00     STATE3
10:00:00    STATE1
14:00:00    STATE2
15:00:00    STATE3
```

I'm using Grafana to create a pie chart that tells me the percentage of time spent in each state. I wrote the following code:

```
from(bucket: "TheBucket")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(<some filters>)
|> elapsed()
|> yield(name: "sum")
```

but `elapsed()` looks backward so it's giving me the time between the last state and the current so I have something like:

```
STATE2     2HR
STATE3     5HR
STATE1     1HR
STATE2     4HR
STATE3     1HR
```

I don't want to know that it took X time to transition to a state, I want to know that the system was in a state for X time. I need the duration spent in the state so the data should look like this

```
STATE1     2HR
STATE2     5HR
STATE3     1HR
STATE1     4HR
STATE2     1HR
```

There are two things I need help with

1. Is there a way to get `elapsed()` to look forward or is there some other function that will give me the total time spent in a given state?
2. I also want to combine certain states into a larger bucket. For example, STATE1 and STATE2 belong to a larger category so I want to combine their total duration into a new state like STATE_A.